# Ubuntu on Macbook Air 7.2

Tags: wireless, suspend, webcam, macbook-air

I am having a few problems with running Ubuntu 15.04 on a Macbook Air 7.2. Namely the webcam, WiFi and it doesn't wake up when I close the lid.

Googling the 7.2 version with Ubuntu doesn't bring up anything, nor is that version mentioned on the Ubuntu wiki.

Has anyone got these things working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this install guide](http://lesavik.net/post/getting-ubuntu-linux-to-work-on-macbook-air-7.2/), the latest version (16.04) has support for WiFi on the 7,2.

You may need run `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` to install it.

There are also now [drivers for the webcam](https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie/wiki/Get-Started).

Answer (score 0):

well , ubuntu is not the best running OS on a macbook there are still some issues that have not yet solved ..

Like , the webcam, wifi , and the closing lid problem ..

there are workarounds for some . but not for all ..

check out this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Wily , not exactly your specified model , but its almost the same .

- the webcame will not work !! sorry ... i dont think there is anything you can do .
- for the wifi .. all you need to do is update your system .. easyest way would be to connect an android phone via USB and do USB tethering.
- there is a strange bug that causes the brightness to be set to only either 100% or 0 after suspend .. the above link gives you a workaround but . for me it only messed everything up .. so what i did  is to change the power setting so that when the lid is closed it would not suspend ..it sucks but , better than restarting every time

.. so , i'll let you know if i come up with anything to fix the other issues .